# XML Deserialization - xmlns not expected

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

/I have an error when I tried to deserialize a xml file:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). ---> <MessageIpBNotifGetInventaire xmlns='http://www.idele.fr/XML/Schema/'> was not expected.
```

The section of my XML that was a problem looks like this:

```
<ns2:MessageIpBNotifGetInventaire xmlns="http://www.fiea.org/types/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.idele.fr/XML/Schema/">
```

My class is defined like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.idele.fr/XML/Schema/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("MessageIpBNotifGetInventaire", Namespace = "http://www.idele.fr/XML/Schema/", IsNullable = false)]

public partial class MessageIpBNotifGetInventaire {
```

Here is my deserialization code

```
using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(reponseSpecifique.MessageZip))
            {
                using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(inputStream))
                {
                    zipFile.Save("D:\\Test.zip");
                    foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zipFile)
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            zipEntry.Extract(outputStream);
                            outputStream.Position = 0;
                            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(outputStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
                            {

                                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(outputStream);
                                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MessageIpBNotifGetInventaire));
                                MessageIpBNotifGetInventaire messageRetour = (MessageIpBNotifGetInventaire)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where is your class code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the namespace in your `XmlRootAttribute` definition doesn't match that in the XML document itself. One has a `/` at the end and the other doesn't.

You might think, don't those URLs point to the same thing, but actually using URLS as namespaces is just a convention (one I don't follow myself, I prefer using `urn:companyname:schemas:appname` or something along those lines), and the strings do have to match exactly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Even adding the / , I get the error message.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at this again yet. I suggest double-checking that you have fixed the namespaces in all element declarations if you have more than in the example in the question, and also see if you can produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Doing that may help you spot your own error anyway.